# Previous month with month name in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a month "August" and need a formula that gives me the name of the month before.

```
=TEXT(EDATE("August"; -1); "MMMM")
```

This does not work, as EDATE expects a DATE(). Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you can use month as a number, I would recommend you

```
=TEXT(EDATE(DATE(2016, 8, 1); -1); "MMMM")
```

for example

If not

```
=TEXT(EDATE(DATE(DATEVALUE("August 01, 2016")); -1); "MMMM")
```

Comment: Perfect! With relative cell reference, this worked: =TEXT(EDATE(DATE(B1; DATEVALUE(C1 & " 01 " & B1); 1); -1); "MMMM")

B1 is the year, C1 e.g. "August".

Answer (score 11):

All you need is the following formula:

`=text(EDATE(today();-1); "MMMM")`